# Wordpress Customize the widget partent css and parent of parent css

Tags: css, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to change the color of the parent and the sub parent category into two different colours. Currently using the following code for my widget side tab.

```
.widget ul {background: gray;padding-top: 1px;}
.widget ul li {background:lightgray;margin: 1px;}
.widget ul a{background-color:darkgray;padding:1px;}
```

looking to change the font colour. I have tried many options but still not getting it right.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.widget ul li.parent > a {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a Tone.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing your HTML structure, but are each of the sub-parent links ('Access Control', 'Electronic locks', etc) their own `ul` tags?

If so, could you not target each of their first `li`'s like this:

```
.widget ul > li:first-of-type > a {
    color: red;
    /* INSERT STYLES */    
}
```

This would target all `ul`s' first `li > a` elements, as in the image on the right.

Comment: www.secsa.co.za. Is the website.